# NSTimer is not calling in background method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nstimer

I got stuck in a problem. I'm trying to run a timer in a method which itself is in background resulting my timer is not initiating. I got to know some where that timer can't be initialized in background so is there any way to do this?

Comment: use `dispatch_after`, `NSTimer` won't work in backbroud thread without `NSRunloop`

Comment: Please explain in more detail what exactly I should do in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the operation on main thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and then

```
- (void)initTimer {
// Init your timer here.
}
```

Comment: Timer init operation should be put inside initTimer method.

Comment: Didn't get your idea.

Comment: Your answer is "use the main thread" but the OP wants to run his method, via a timer, in a background thread.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, you can't init a timer in background thread.

Comment: You can if you use GCD.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @yibuyiqu your "initTimer" method will not be called on background thread. OP has already tried this thats why question title is 
"NSTimer is not calling in background method". i dont why someone upvotes this answer.

Comment: @pawan Yeah the upvote is suspicious for sure, given the answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: pawan & trojanfoe, it is just the different way to implement the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Background Fetch in ios7 to run code on background

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// provide value as required. Time here is 3 sec
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC); 

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do your task
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Bryan Chen, you can schedule a method to be run *on the current thread* using the following code:

```
dispatch_time_t when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(when, dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self myTimedMethod];
});
```

You cannot use `NSTimer` in a background thread unless you are maintaining a *run loop* on that thread.